# Making ItemizedOverlay onTap action trigger without user input to make a balloon visible when changing to screen activity

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I have a MapView in my project where I display a set of items with ItemizedOverlay.

When a user taps one of the items a balloon is displayed over it with some info.

Now, what I am trying to achieve is **when changing to the map activity screen have a balloon show up without the user tap the screen**... like an initialization, where I make a balloon already visible without user input.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this. While you are initially displaying the set of items on `ItemizedOverlay`, and as you identify the item that should show the balloon, run `onTap` method for that item's index. If items are already displayed, just identify or retrieve the index for item in question, and run `onTap` for it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using the following command:

```
itemizedoverlay.onTap(itemizedoverlay.getItem(0).getPoint(), mapView);
```

The object `itemizedoverlay` is an instance of my extension of `ItemizedOverlay`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override onResume for your MapView? It will be called everytime your activity goes to foreground.

Hope it helps!